# The service certificate is not provided for target '###' Specify a service certificate in ClientCredentials

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have implemented a test Client / Server that implements `UserName` message authentication over WCF.  It *almost* all works however I have fallen at the last hurdle.

I get an `InvalidOperationException` that reads

> The service certificate is not provided for target 'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/EvalServiceLibrary/Service1/'. Specify a service certificate in ClientCredentials.

Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your requiring a certificate for security and your client code is not supplying the certificate on request.  [WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732391.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Include something like this in your **client** configuration file:

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="http://example.com/Myservice.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="Core.IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehaviour" >
   <identity>
    <dns value="SampleServiceCertificate"/>
   </identity>
 </endpoint>
</client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myServiceBehaviour">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" findValue="SampleServiceCertificate" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"  />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>            
      </endpointBehaviors>          
    </behaviors>
```

Comment: Your answer did not work. I am now getting the error: Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'SampleServiceCertificate'.

Comment: @MichaelS.Miller - StoreName 'My' and FindValue 'SampleServiceCertificate' are just examples I gave, you should modify these values to match YOUR installed certificate.

Comment: I was using my certificate. However, it turns out that someone misspelled the name of the certificate in the email when I asked them the name of the certificate, and I just copy/pasted it into the code without looking at it. Once I realized the "Service" was not spelled "Servcie" it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your client needs to be able to authenticate the service by reference to an X509certificate, the public key of which it will use to encrypt messages sent to the service.

The service certificate is identified on the client side by the ServiceCertificate property of the ClientCredentials. The error message is telling you that your configuration/code hasn't set this up correctly. If you post your code/config we may be able to tell you what's wrong.